# Where does MapInfo store its error and log files?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, sql-server

I am having  errors opening a table with spatial co-ordinates in Microsoft SQL and my question in [gis.stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13436/loading-table-mssql-from-database-always-crashes-mapinfo). I want to know where are the error and log files of Mapinfo stored. I searched over the Mapinfo installation but was unable to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapInfo doesn't have specific error and log files. You might want to check the Event log under Windows. Another thing to try out would be to trace your ODBC connection or the statements send thru this. Maybe that would give you a hint on the problem.